# How to parse and import a text file into multiple MySQL table fields and records

Tags: mysql, text, import, text-parsing

What is the optimal method to parse and import a single text file into multiple database records, in 3 columns?  Assume I have the MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `text` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `notes` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I want to populate that MySQL table with a text (.txt) file that has the following attributes:

- 3.2MB file size
- 114,589 lines
- 3,085,881 characters (with spaces)
- 72,251 paragraphs

The text content is formatted into several years of notes with records for each day.  I would like a separate database record for each day.  The text header for each day/date is in the format:

```
=======================  
Xxx, Mmm Dd, YY  
=======================
```

where:

```
Xxx = 3 character day of week (e.g. Thu)  
Mmm = 3 character Month (e.g. Aug)  
Dd = 1 or 2 numeral Day (e.g. 28 for Aug 28th)  
YY = 2 numeral year (e.g. 16)
```

e.g. Sun, Aug 28, 16

This date header is followed by random paragraphs of textual notes specific to that day.  The text may also include other instances of ====== , together with arbitrary non-escaped field insert characters (e.g. comma, open parenthesis, close parenthesis, semi-colon, etc)

Comment: Use a text editor with regex replace to convert the content to an SQL insert statement :-)

Comment: You are asking two questions in one. The hard question, which is very dependent on the text file, is how to create a proper CSV or other delimited file from your text file. The other one, much easier, is how to import a CSV to a table...